# VBA Selecting Yesterday in a Slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select yesterday's date in a slicer in my workbook when it is opened automatically.

Currently, I am receiving no errors but also no result. My slicer VBA name is Slicer_Date.

This is my code.

```
Sub ForNow()
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date")
    .ClearManualFilter
    For Each myitem In .SlicerItems
        If myitem.Name = Date - 1 Then
            myitem.Selected = True
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("slicer_date")
    .ClearManualFilter
    For Each myitem In .SlicerItems
        myitem.Selected = CDate(myitem.Name) = Date - 1
    Next myitem
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: It works by selecting the slicer item then fails with a "type mismatch" on this line myitem.Selected = CDate(myitem.Name) = Date

Comment: When it fails what is the value of `myitem.Name` ?

Comment: Date = 19/10/2018

Comment: Sorry - out of ideas.  The code I posted worked in testing but I don't have the same dataset so...

Comment: I think that it gets a day off because Date -1  should be the 18/10/2018

Comment: Just tested again and it's still OK for me (and it's still oct 18 here...)

Comment: More experimenting then. Doesn't error but doesn't work with CDate removed